# Unprovability of $\exists x\forall u\exists y((R(x,x)\vee\neg R(x,u))\vee(R(y,x)\&\neg R(y,u)))$

Tags: logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic, model-theory, proof-theory

Could you please check my solution? It is short and simple but I doubt somehow...

> Prove the following formula: $\exists x\forall u\exists y((R(x,x)\vee\neg R(x,u))\vee(R(y,x)\&\neg R(y,u)))$.

I state it is unprovable: consider $x,u,y\in\mathbb N_0$ and let $R(x,y)\Longleftrightarrow x<y$. Then we obtain $\exists x\forall u\exists y(x<x\vee x\geqslant u\vee(y<x\:\&\:y\geqslant u))$.

Let $x=n$ and  let $u=n+1$. Our formula claims $\exists y(n<n\vee n\geqslant n+1\vee(y<n\:\&\:y\geqslant n+1))$. But that is obviously false: firstly, $n<n$ and $n\geqslant n+1$ both do not hold; secondly, the following system is inconsistent:
$$\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   y<n\\
   y\geqslant n+1
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$$

The formula is invalid, so it is unprovable.

Comment: I am confused by your query.  As I understand it, your analysis indicates that when $R(x,y)\Longleftrightarrow x<y$, that the conjecture is **false** and therefore unprovable.  However, the impression I got from the start of your query is that you were asserting that the conjecture is unprovable (i.e. presumably demonstrably false) for **any** specification of $R(x,y)$.  If I am interpreting your query correctly, your analysis is insufficient, because you only focused on 1 sample specification for $R(x,y)$.

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense to me. If the task was to prove the given formula as a theorem of first-order logic in the language of $R$, then exhibiting a model in which the given formula is false shows that the task is impossible. And I don't see any mistakes in your work.

Comment: @user2661923, but Gödel's completeness theorem states, in particular, that a formula is provable only if it is valid (i.e. true for any interpretation). I've found an interpretation for which validity does not hold. That must imply unprovability, mustn't it?

Comment: Normally, at this point, I would realize that I am way out of my depth, and delete my previous comment.  Here, I think it is better to leave the previous comment as is, and have it merely indicate that I am generally ignorant of the corresponding Math, and that I was confused by the query.

Comment: @user2661923, it's all right! At least, thank you for your interest : )

Comment: @Karl, thank you! My academic advisor said this formula is provable. That's the reason of my doubts. Probably, he played a trick on me... : )

Comment: I thought it was not provable. Take a two element domain $\{a,b\}$ and $R=\{(a,b),(b,a)\}$. Looking at cases shows the formula does not hold. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnStell, yes, you are right. Thank you for another counterexample: it's even simpler than mine!

Comment: @JohnStell, one can generalize you counterexample for an arbitrary domain $X$ such that $|X|>1$ and $R(a,b)\Longleftrightarrow a\ne b$, cannot he?

Comment: sorry, I'm not so sure about that now, I think I made a mistake

Comment: Also, it's an $\exists...$ formula, so it's not satisfied by the empty model.

Comment: Everything is provable with the 'right' premises or inference rules.

Comment: @Karl: in standard treatments of first-order logic, models are required to be non-empty.

Comment: @Karl, aren't non-emptiness a part of the definition of a model? Cause if no, any $\exists$-formula is invalid. That seems strange...

Comment: I guess that's conventional, yeah - see Rob's comment.